# VBARuntimeError9

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba

Trying to upload data from Excel to Microsoft SQL by VBA, got a runtime error '9', it would be good if someone can help please

```vb
    Sub Update()
        Dim sql As String

        Dim Volume As Range
        Set Volume = Range("D7:D37")

        Dim Date1 As Range
        Set Date1 = Range("B7:B37")

        Dim DayOfweek As Range
        Set DayOfweek = Range("C7:C37")
        sql = "SET NOCOUNT ON"
        sql = sql & Range("D7:D37").Offset(0, 4).Text
        sql = sql & " SET NOCOUNT OFF"
        sql = sql & " SELECT * FROM WorkDBDialler.dbo.t_DJ0529_interactive_collections_SMS_Volumes_VBL_Weekday_test      

ActiveWorkbook.Connections("1").OLEDBConnection.sql = sql

        Range("Table1").ListObject.QueryTable.sql = sql
        Range("Table1").ListObject.QueryTable.Refresh
        MsgBox "Updated"
    End Sub
```

Comment: Try these .. Change `sql = "SET NOCOUNT ON"` to `sql = "SET NOCOUNT ON "` and also change `ActiveWorkbook.Connections("1").OLEDBConnection.sql` to `ActiveWorkbook.Connections("1").OLEDBConnection`

Comment: I found no traces of `sql` property in the [oledbconnection object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.oledbconnection).

Comment: Thank you for your help, However, It is still not working.

Comment: What is the idea of this line? `    sql = sql & " SELECT * FROM WorkDBDialler.dbo.t_DJ0529_interactive_collections_SMS_Volumes_VBL_Weekday_test **ActiveWorkbook.Connections("1").OLEDBConnection.sql = sql**` Why are the `**` needed? The `=sql` at the end is a bit meaningless.